# LZ4: Compression of compressed image formats

Tags: c++, c, compression, lz4

I am using [LZ4 compressor](https://github.com/lz4/lz4) C lib. Some of the files I compress are JPG and PNGs. For some reason, which I fail to understand, the method

```
 int compressedSize =   LZ4_compress_default((char*)data,
            compressedData, uncompressedSize, uncompressedSize);
```

Sometimes returns negative values for images(or zero), which I am compressing.

For example, I am compressing two standard JPG images. One returns with a value  '-236', while the second returns fine the number of compressed bytes, which means the first has failed to compress. Zero return means LZ4 failed to compress. I have no idea what -236 means. Is it because the source data is already compressed to some extent?

Comment: I would guess that the compressed version actually got larger than the original (which is not uncommon with JPEG, try to zip a jpeg image and see the results for yourself), and hence the negative number.

Comment: Have you checked exampled @ https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/dev/examples/compress_functions.c after line 248. i.e. usage of maxcompsize

Comment: I thought that the function returned the number of bytes that were gained with the compression (original_size - compressed_size), but it seems like I was wrong. The lz4 manual says about the return value: _return : the number of bytes written into buffer 'dest' (necessarily <= maxOutputSize)
or 0 if compression fails_. It does not seem to mention negative values.

Comment: @HRgiger you got a point

Comment: Aside from fixing the error, you should not be bothering trying to compress already compressed files. The result will just be larger.

Comment: @MarkAdler That's not the purpose.I am writing a zip like program to pack many different files into one.

Comment: Then have a store mode like zip does in your "zip like program" to avoid wasting time trying to compress things that are already compressed.

Comment: @MarkAdler good Idea,thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function return definition is:

> ```
>   return : the number of bytes written into buffer 'dest' (necessarily <= maxOutputSize)
>            or 0 if compression fails
> ```

If the the compression resulted in a size larger than `uncompressedSize`, which is highly likely with an already compressed file, the function will fail.  However that does not explain why it has returned a negative value - that is not documented.  But it remains the case that if you need to accommodate compressed files, you need to allow for the file size to increase by providing a larger buffer.

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/dev/lib/lz4.c), the return value is generated in `LZ4_compress_generic()` by:

```
return (int) (((char*)op)-dest);
```

The pointer arithmetic would return a negative value if `op` < `dest`, though looking at the code, it is hard to see how that might occur.  If it is a concern (and certainly if just providing a larger destination buffer does not resolve the issue), I suggest that you step through the code in your debugger to determine what the problem is.

Comment: const size_t max_dst_size = LZ4_compressBound(src_size);  solves the problem